# How do I determine the amount of times I append something to a nested hash?

Tags: perl, oop, loops, hash

I'm working with a dataset that is going to require me to resort to some type of OOP, I think.  I don't have much experience with this.  Basically, I'm parsing data in a `foreach` loop, and adding the results to a hash.

There will only be about 8 different values, at least at this time, but multiple "hits" of these values.  Let's say I create the value `color=>white`.  Well, `color=>white` is going to come up again, and when I append it to the hash, it's just going to overwrite the existing `color=>white`.

What I'm hoping for is to determine the amount of times I append `color=>white`.  Now, obviously there's a simple, dumb way to do that - a switch of some kind, testing various conditions.  Only things are dynamic.  Things occasionally change.  So I need to be able to handle that without constantly changing the script.

So I ideally, in the end, I'd be able to check the hash for each key/value and see how many times it occurred, without any idea of which key/value I'm looking for.

Does anyone have any advice here?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a multi-level hash where the first level is the attribute name, the next level is the value, and the value of that is the count.

```
my @data = qw(
    color white
    color blue
    color white
    size  10
    size  20
    size  10
    color yellow
    color blue
    color white
);

my %hash;
while (@data) {
    my ($key, $value) = splice @data, 0, 2;
    $hash{$key}{$value}++;
}

for my $key (keys %hash) {
    for my $value (keys %{$hash{$key}}) {
        print "'$key' was '$value' $hash{$key}{$value} times\n"
    }
}
```

which prints:

```
'color' was 'white' 3 times
'color' was 'blue' 2 times
'color' was 'yellow' 1 times
'size' was '10' 2 times
'size' was '20' 1 times
```

Comment: Yep.  [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) has some other examples, and there's lots of other perldoc on related topics.  (Not to mention that every good Perl book should cover this topic.)

Answer (score 2):

Perl has this method for emulating multi-level associative arrays using a single hash.  It's inherited from AWK, is ancient and flawed, and you shouldn't use it… but it's kind of interesting anyhow.

```
my %hash;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($key, @values) = split;
    $hash{$key, $_}++ for @values;
}

while (my ($keys, $count) = each %hash) {
    my ($key, $value) = split /\Q$;/, $keys;
    print "$key => $value => $count\n";
}

__DATA__
color white blue red green
size small medium
color red orange purple
size medium large
```

Produces something like

```
color => blue => 1
color => green => 1
color => orange => 1
color => purple => 1
color => red => 2
color => white => 1
size => large => 1
size => medium => 2
size => small => 1
```

though hash order is unpredictable.

See Eric Strom's answer (and read [perldoc perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html) and [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)) for the modern and better solution.